# ODBC Driver for c++

Tags: c++, csv, odbc

if any one had written a ODBC driver using c++, and need to manipulate csv file (means that the as the database using a csv file). please help me

Comment: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My short idea is to use [MySQL ODBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) with the [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html)

Comment: thanks, i didn't get the idea 100% can you please enplane little bit. and if you can please send me sample coding of it.